# Create database creates a db with a #mysql50# before the name

Tags: mysql, mysql5.7

Just in the last day, whenever I create a new database, it is prepending the database name with:

```
#mysql50#
```

And I am unable to connect to this database. Im having real issues on our PROD server as we create a new database often. Please see the image below.

[image: Error]

We're running the following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `bru_1111-userId`;
```

Im unsure what to do? Its a hosted MYSQL with Azure - so I have no idea how to login and delete folders as suggested here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34385/strange-mysql-database-that-i-cant-select

Please help!

Comment: Database names can only be "Alphanumerics and hyphens" according to Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules. Are you sure the database name was successfully changed?

Comment: What do you mean changed? It seems like Microsoft rolled out a patch that has made our database NOT like hyphens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So our fix for this was to make sure databases werent created with any hyphens in them. My suspicion here is the DB was upgraded and this rule of no hyphens enforced on our Azure Mysql servers. Now we use underscores instead.